# Android: how to HTTP post this?

Tags: android, http-post

I am sorry, I am going mad, I have tried everything, but nothing seems to work.

I need to do HTTP Post **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

of this:

```
'type' : 'Fb',
'data' : 
[
    'fbId' : '1234',
    'name' : 'Jo G',
    'bday' : '10/10/1999',
    'gender' : 'Fermal',
    'email' : 'jo@mail.com'
]
```

Comment: you want to post the entire string as a single key=value in POST, or as individual `type=fb&data[fbid]=1234&etc...`?

Comment: @KevinDTimm please Kevin, is that the same thing?

Comment: @MarcB thanks a lot Mark !!! I am afraid I will need to try both, not sure which one the server wants